# Switching out the autocomplete items in a user based entity reference

Tags: 8, entities

I'm working with an entity reference field in Drupal 8.3. It resides on a node and references users using the autocomplete widget. I have it setup to use an entity reference view for both what it is doing the lookup on and what it is showing. However no matter what modifications I seem to make to the view the auto complete always returns the referenced email address the new search criteria from the view is working ( it looks up the email by first or last name). Instead of the email however, I'm trying to instead show the users first name and last name as listed on the user entity.

I'm not sure if this is a bug in 8 as I remember this working in 7. Please let me know if there is anything I'm missing. If you need more info please just let me know. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles on this... Its currently broken in 8.0x+ https://www.drupal.org/node/2174633